# Generate deterministic unique fixed length filename string from multiple input strings

Tags: java, string, hash, filenames, deterministic

I have multiple Strings that I would like to use to generate a single, fixed length, deterministic string from. I am trying to ensure uniqueness in a database, and also will be using the string for filenames; so I will need to avoid collisions as best as possible, and need to avoid special characters. I also need it to be deterministic so that the same three strings in the same order will produce the same output string.

I thought of concatenating the strings on a known delimiter, and base64 encoding. However that is not fixed length.

I thought of concatenating the strings, getting a hash from that string, and base64 encoding that. However by default base64 has special characters which windoze will complain about, and this seems like bad practice.

Now I'm doing this, which also feels ugly:

```
protected UUID parseUUID() {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add(stringOne);
        strings.add(stringTwo);
        strings.add(stringThree);

        strings.removeIf(str -> str == null || str.isEmpty());
        for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            String string = strings.get(i);
            string = string.replace("|", "\\|");
            strings.set(i, string);
        }
        String input = String.join("|", strings);
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(input.getBytes());

        return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(hash);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**What are the odds of collision with this method? What is the best way to generate a deterministic fixed length string suitable for a filename from multiple input strings? Surely this is not it.**

Comment: The only special characters in base64 are `+` and `/`, which you could easily change to `'_'` and `'-'`. That solves the special character problem. It doesn't solve the uniqueness problem, though. You still have the same chance of collision that you end up with any hash code. And that depends on the length of the hash code.

Comment: It's unclear whether you want the same hash code for the three strings, regardless of the order in which they're presented. That is, will the strings ("A", "B", "C") generate the same has code as ("B", "A", "C")?

Comment: I want ("A", "B", "C") to always generate the same string. ("B", "A", "C") should generate a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came up with for now is:

```
protected String parseHash() {
    try {
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        strings.add("one");
        strings.add("two");
        strings.add("three");

        strings.removeIf(str -> str == null || str.isEmpty());
        for(int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            String string = strings.get(i);
            string = string.replace("|", "\\|");
            strings.set(i, string);
        }
        String input = String.join("|", strings);
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(input.getBytes());
        return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hash);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I've read `UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(hash);` will compute the md5 of my given hash, which reduces the resolution of the hash. Using the raw hex of the hash seems to be the most elegant way I can think of, but I am of course open to other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I dont really get it, what is hindering you to just use a hash function like you already do? They are designed to do exactly what you want to achieve (provided I got you correct). You can simply concatenate your Strings, apply a hash function and store the hash.

Collisions are possible of course, but this will always be the case when trying to map an infinite space to a finite one.

Comment: There is nothing "wrong" with my approach, but I do consider it to be less than graceful. I was more curious how feeding a sha-256 hash into a UUID would affect the chance of collision on the end string. I also wanted to see how some other developers gracefully solved this problem.